# Install windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, windows

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to install windows 10 alongside.I have seen some videos on YouTube of how to do it.So, the first step is to open GParted and unmount
/dev/sda2 partition ,but when I click "unmount" ,it says:
"Could not unmount /dev/sda2
# unmount -v '/'
unmount /:target is busy
"
What should I do?

Comment: Is /dev/sda2 where your current Ubuntu os resides?

Comment: Whilst it is possible to do it the way you suggest, most people recommend installing Windows first then Ubuntu. One of the problems is that installing Windows sometimes wrecks your Ubuntu partition / grub boatloader - windows doesn’t like sharing with Ubuntu! If you do it the other way round, the Windows installer never knows about the other os.